error when installing coco annotator through docker desktop
I have run "git clone https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator" in a folder, and cd coco-annotator. After that I ran "docker-compose up", then it always showed me
"unexpected EOF".
First, I thought there may be some questions with my installation of docker, because my pc was win11 home. However, when I ran "docker run hello-world", it ran successfully. And there were no related questions online.
I just want to install coco annotator
